# Exchange 2010 to 2016 migration - Is it a requirement to enable Outlook Anywhere on Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange

If not, what will happen with users that are already migrated to Exchange 2016 but still have access to a shared mailbox on Exchange 2010?

Will their Outlook client (2010 updated with required patches) connect to their primary mailbox over MAPI/HTTP and simultaneously connect to the shared mailbox over MAPI/RPC ?

Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a requirement to enable Outlook Anywhere for full co-existence to take place.

If they have the Shared Mailbox connected as an additional mailbox, then the connection will fail. It will need to be removed and reconnected. That is actually an old problem with shared mailboxes, as Outlook cannot update the connection point on its own in that scenario. I have seen problems with shared mailboxes in migrations all the way back to Exchange 2000.

If the Shared Mailbox is connected as an additional ACCOUNT, then the connection will continue to work, because as far as Outlook is concerned, the connection hasn't changed.

Comment: Thank you Sembee. This is the best answer I've gotten out of all the times I asked this question.